# jboss problem with JMXConnectorServer

Tags: java, jboss

I just installed JBoss and tried to run it from Eclipse. When I first tried to run it I got an error stating that ports 8080 and 1098 are already being bound to something else. I changed those in the config files. Here is example of where I changes port 1098 to 10098

```
    <bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
       <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
       <property name="bindingName">RmiPort</property>
       <property name="port">10098</property>
       <property name="description">Socket Naming service uses to receive RMI requests from client proxies</property>
    </bean>
```

After this the port errors went away but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error installing to Start: name=jboss.remoting:protocol=rmi,service=JMXConnectorServer state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BaseClassLoader@dc93be{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jmx-remoting.sar/} classLoader is not connected to a domain (probably undeployed?) for class javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:793)
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:441)
........
```

Do you know what the problem could be or how to go about approaching it?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing JBoss's ports is not something to be done lightly, because it talks to itself a lot.  If you change the ports it listens on, it loses that communication.

Firstly, it is better to try and shut down the other processes that are listening on those ports. It's either going tio be other web servers, application servers, or sometimes things like thunderbird and firefox grab those ports.

If that's not an option, then it's better to bind jboss to its own IP address, but that's only practical on unix/linux.

So if you really want to shift JBoss on to a different set of ports, then you can [follow the instructions here](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine)

Answer (score 1):

look into your processes
ps -f 
and kill the processes that are hanging.
That seemed to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i am going with Kumaria's answer , as i also faced this issue on one of my Jboss servers and after checking with the linux command `ps -ef|grep java` i got to know there were multiple instances running of same application and there were few dependency instances which were consuming those applications. so i just killed all those multiple instances and dependencies with `kill -9 instanceNumber` and restarted the main application and it worked :)